# addClass dentro da this

Tags: jquery

Tenho esse HTML:

```
<div class="botao">
   <div class="seta"></div>
</div>
```

Em Jquery qundo se clica no botão, adiciono uma classe nele assim:

```
$(this).addClass('botao_ativo');
```

Como eu adiciono uma classe na class SETA? Tentei assim, mas não foi:

```
$(this '.seta').addClass('seta_ativa');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se `.seta` for descendente de `this` podes fazer assim:

```
$(this).find('.seta').addClass('seta_ativa');
// ou alternativamente:
$('.seta', this).addClass('seta_ativa');
```

Exemplo:

```js
$('.botao').on('click', function() {
  $('.seta', this).addClass('seta_ativa');
});
```

```css
.seta_ativa {
  background-color: #eaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="botao">
  <div class="seta">Clique aqui</div>
</div>
```

No caso geral seria:

```
$('.seta').addClass('seta_ativa');
```